# Adding spaces between words evenly from left to right untill a certain length

Tags: python

Receiving a string that has 2 or more words and a certain length, I need to insert spaces uniformly between words, adding additional spaces between words from left to right. Let's say I receive "Hello I'm John" and a length of 17, it should return:`'Hello   I'm  John`

I have tried many different ways and I couldn't do the left-to-right requirement.

This is what I have now:

```
 if ' ' in string:
        final_string=''
        string=string.split()
        for i in range(len(string)):
            if string[i]==string[-1]:
                final_string+=string[i]
            else:
                final_string+=string[i]+'  '
print(final_string)
```

Output:
`Hello   I'm  John`

which gives me a length greater than what I want...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I tried to find a duplicate for this, but then I found out that the standard library tool I had in mind doesn't actually do this. However, I'm still not clear on the thought process here - what part of the code shown here, is intended to care about the "length of 17"? *How do you want the program to know* the desired total length? (Also: the length of this output seems to be 16, which is not greater than 17. Do you want to make sure the output length is **exactly** 17? If so, where should the "extra" space go?)

Comment: My bad... the output length should be exactly 17( I forgot a space)(the program knows the desired length, because the user inputs it). Nothing here in this part of the code cares about the length of 17,(it's incomplete...-I had a while loop that cares about that ). Any more doubts or something that is unclear please ask!!

Comment: I rollbacked your question text to the previous revision. It became unclear with most of the text gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably something like this?

```
words = cad_carateres.split()
total_nb_of_spaces_to_add = total_string_length - len(cad_carateres)

nb_of_spaces_to_add_list = [total_nb_of_spaces_to_add // (len(words) - 1) 
+ int(i < (total_nb_of_spaces_to_add % (len(words) - 1))) 
                   for i in range(len(words) - 1)]  + [0]

result = ' '.join([w + ' ' * (nb_of_spaces_to_add) 
             for w, nb_of_spaces_to_add in zip(words, nb_of_spaces_to_add_list)])
```

First line - you [split](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) your line into words

Second line - how many spaces, in total, we need to add.

Third line - suppose that we need to add 20 spaces, and we have 7 words in total (thus, 6 gaps where we add additional spaces). Let's add [3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2] spaces in these gaps, and, obviously 0 spaces after the last word. `nb_of_spaces_to_add_list` will contain the list like [3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0]

The last line line - [join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) the padded (with spaces, their number comes from `nb_of_spaces_to_add_list`) words into the string - this is your result! I also use [zip](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) function to convert 2 one-dimensional lists (words and number of spaces to add) into a two-dimensional list, this allows me to use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

Comment: @03Sparta : see `+ ' ' * (max_length - len(w))` bit? It adds extra spaces, as you have requested!

Comment: so that the total length is equal to `max_length`

Comment: BTW if this answers your question, could you accept my answer and upvote it?

Comment: I still can't upvote, since i dont have more that 15 reputation...

Comment: @03Sparta Maybe you could give a more detailed explanation of your spaces requirement - could you edit your question?

Comment: @03Sparta updated! if this is what you need, could you confirm and I will explain what's going on in these lines

Comment: @03Sparta added some explanations, hope this helps. Try to play with the code, change it here and there, this should help you to familiarise with the new functions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking like something like this?

```
def main():
    sentence="Hello my name is John"
    words=sentence.split()
    new_sentence="  ".join(words)
    print(new_sentence)
main()
```